# Controlling the URL in a Page Viewer Web Part

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, page-viewer-web-part

We are attempting to build a connection between a SharePoint list and another SharePoint page with a Page Viewer web part embedded on it. What I can't seem to wrap my brain around is how can we control the URL of the Page Viewer web part dynamically without resorting to custom code.

Here's the way we envision this working. There is a list of events that contains some high level data about it(the event). We want the user to be able to click on the event and be taken to another SharePoint page that displays the detail data about the event from the system that actually manages all of the events. Setting up the link to point to the SharePoint page is, obviously, not an issue, the question is, how do we pass the necessary information to that (SharePoint) page so that it can pass it to the source system (presumably using query string arguments) so that the detail data for the specific event is what get's displayed in the Page Viewer web part?

We are using SharePoint 2013 Enterprise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the page in the page viewer web part is really another SharePoint page, I don't think a PVWP is the right solution here. If we're talking about event details, you'd be better off adding two list view web parts to the page... the first showing the event list/title/etc, and the second showing the event details. Link the web parts together so that a user can select an event from the first webpart, and a filtered view of the event details will be presented on the right.

You could always have a rich text field on the list if you need more robust formatting of event details with photos and such; everything would still be contained within a single list with no additional pages needed.

If you're trying to cobble together a PVWP you'll have all sorts of other issues, such as tricking it into thinking it's in a dialog so you don't see the navigation and everything in your PVWP as well as on the top of the parent page.

Comment: The page that will be presented within the Page Viewer web part is not a SharePoint page but is being served up by another web site. I just need to get it the Event ID. Also the details of the event are quite extensive and we have already decided that it will be way too difficult to display them without creating a custom web part which we are really trying to avoid. Plus the detail page functionality is already built within the other system.

Comment: Linking the event list to any webpart would allow a user to be able to select the event, and put the item ID in the URL string, but you're still going to need customization to push that to your PVWP. You will either need to customize the event list to provide a mechanism to select the event and spit out an ID, or you have to customize the PVWP to be smart enough to handle that lookup. You're customizing anyway, there's no way that I can think of to do what you want OOTB.

Comment: I suspected that but was hoping that I was wrong :-). Thanks, I appreciate your response.